# What permissions do I need to run external js (Facebook-SDK) in a Chrome extension popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing my first Chrome Extensions and I want to run this script in my popup.js:

```js
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=############";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

But it doesn't load, and I see no errors in console.

Comment: I edited the manifest according to this, but it still doesn't work (I'm not getting any errors but the plugins I want to implement just don't appear).

Comment: Thanks for helping me use the console properly. I added "https://" into the script and now it is partially working. I checked the console and now another url is blocked (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/....), how can I add it to the privacy settings? I dont feel very comfortable with this syntax.

Comment: Ok I did it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

- The errors were shown in the popup's console: rightclick the popup, then `Inspect`
- Script `src` didn't specify `https` so current scheme `chrome-extension:` was used.

  ```js
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=############";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  ```
- To allow the script [contentSecurityPolicy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) should be specified in manifest.json:

  ```js
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net/ https://graph.facebook.com/; object-src 'self'"
  ```
- To allow the dependent scripts loaded by SDK permissions in manifest.json were needed:

  ```js
    "permissions": [
      "webNavigation",
      "https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js*",
      "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/*"
    ]
  ```
- Since the hash part of URL isn't recognized in manifest.json wildcard `*` should be used.